# Regex for matching string, contains only number and count must be 2 min values

Tags: c#, regex, validation, string-matching

Is there any regex for validating length of a number string for 2 consecutive digits or number

Example :

```
"12541256442545245215" = Count (20)
"125412564425452452"= Count (18)
```

Need a regex to check a string which contains only number and count must be 18 or 20.

I tried using the below regex but it allows length 19 also.

```
^[0-9.]{18,20}$
```

Comment: You can't use an "or" for a quantifier. Remember that "18 or 20" is "18 and then maybe 2 more", and it will be easy to write.

Comment: `^[0-9]{18}(?:[0-9]{2})?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[0-9.]{18}(?:[0-9.]{2})?$
```

About this regex:

```
^            # start
[0-9.]{18}   # match digit or DOT 18 times
(?:          # start non-capturing group
   [0-9.]{2} # match digit or DOT 2 times
)?           # end non-capturing group, ? makes this group *optional*
$            # end
```

If you don't want to allow DOT then use:

```
^[0-9]{18}(?:[0-9]{2})?$
```